# Growth of plant in greenhouse

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The following problem came up in an exam I sat recently.

[image]

I got 113cm, but I'm quite unsure about my method. Is someone able to go through the working and explain the problem? Of course, I don't have access to the official answer yet. I can't remember my exact working but I believe I simply integrated, evaluated the constants and substituted in t=365.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate the equation to get

$$h(t) = 12 k t + \frac{3 \cdot 365}{2 \pi} k \sin{\frac{2 \pi t}{365}} +C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  You are given that

$$h(0) = 84 \implies C=84$$
$$h(75) = 91 \implies 7 = k \left (12 \cdot 75 + \frac{3 \cdot 365}{2 \pi} \sin{\frac{2 \pi \cdot 75}{365}} \right ) \implies k\approx 0.00655737$$

On the longest day of the next (non-leap) year, $t=365$ so that

$$h(365) = 12 (0.00655737) 365 +84\approx 112.7$$

which would seem to agree with your result.